# Why is XCode Organizer console sometimes empty when I connect my iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode, console, organizer

When testing my iPhone app I have found it incredibly useful to log information to the console window.  I think it is amazing that I can send out an adhoc build to my co-workers and if they experience problems I am able to plug their iPhone into my mac and grab their console output.  However, sometimes the console window is blank when we do this.  Why is this the case?  The code has been built with logging enabled.  Besides that, it seems that the console output, when I see it, contains information about not only my app, but other iphone system logging.

Thanks for any insight you can provide.

Comment: Maybe I'll have to answer my own question.  It looks like if I restart XCode then the console gets populated properly.  I'll try this for a little while to see if this always works...if It does then I will answer my own question. :)

I am currently using version 3.2.3 (1683)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It looks like if I restart XCode then the console gets populated properly.  Must be a bug in XCode, but restarting seems to always work.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a new bug in 3.2.3 - older versions worked fine.