# Why doesn't the Xcode Organizer Console show logs from my device?

Tags: xcode, xcode3.2, xcode-organizer

When I plug my device in and run my app, the log output doesn't show up in the Organizer Console. Is there some other place to look for log output? I thought I could find it in Console.app but I'm having trouble.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you're looking in xcode 'organiser' window, which is the correct place.

Are you running foul of this bug:

[Why is XCode Organizer console sometimes empty when I connect my iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965767/why-is-xcode-organizer-console-sometimes-empty-when-i-connect-my-iphone/3133874#3133874)

Essentially you may need to completely quit and restart xcode after connecting the device and/or whenever it stops working.

Comment: I could be. I haven't tried that yet. (Restarting XCode.) Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

I noticed in the Settings app, there is now a Developer entry which has a Logging On/Off switch.  I'm not sure what it does exactly but you might want to try turning it on.