# Capturing iPhone console log when running Instrument's UI Automation

Tags: iphone, xcode, instruments, ios-ui-automation

In Xcode, I can run my application with the console open by using "Run->Console" and then executing a "Build and Run" command.  Now I've written a UI Automation script that I would like to run while capturing the console log.  When I press "record" in instruments, an instance of my application is started and the test is executed, but no output is displayed to the console.  Is there a way to run the two in parallel?  Or to automatically capture what would be displayed to the application's console when running a UI automation script?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running my application through the UI Automation tool the first time, I opened Organizer in Xcode and saw that the console logs were empty.  Thus, I believed that the logs were not being written to even the Organizer console.  I found that this was a bug in my version of Xcode as discussed in this stack overflow question ([Why is XCode Organizer console sometimes empty when I connect my iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965767/why-is-xcode-organizer-console-sometimes-empty-when-i-connect-my-iphone)).  I was eventually able to get my Organizer console log to display while the UI Automation was running.